# How to run php-fpm master process as non root user?

Tags: php, linux, nginx, fpm, nginx-config

How do i run php-fpm master process as non root user

```
root 10275 0.0 0.5 192856 23104 ? Ss Nov20 0:01 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
```